# Utilizing Extended Cox Model with repeated measures and/or time-dependent covariates + wanted end result question

Tags: r, repeated-measures, cox-model

I am working on a survival analysis that looks at time-independent as well as time-dependent variables. I have been reading at length the use of time-dependent variables, which requires an Extended Cox Model. I have also stumbled upon the concept of repeated measures, so my first question:

> Which should I be using? Here is data for a single ID. * indicates dependent on time (t). Event = 1 indicates a failure.

ID, Market, Event, t, Actuals* 
1, 4, 0, 1, 5000
1, 4, 0, 2, 4000
1, 4, 1, 3, 6000

As you can see, the Actuals vary from t to t (in this case months). All of the time-dependent covariate examples I have seen remain dichotomous. Should repeated measures be used instead?

My second question, which may be a stretch, but for the end-game and to make this into an easy to understand presentable for my boss...

> For each ID, I'd like to associate a kind of score, which utilizes all variables and spits out a single value, indicating the likelihood of failure (Event = 1). Is this possible? If so, what is this called? I'd like to do more research on it.

Thank you in advance for any help/insight.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a normal Cox regression to me. The way you present the data is how you normally incorporate time varying covariates. So no need to do anything special.

As to your second question: Possible, but not in line with the logic behind Cox regression. The whole point of Cox regression is that you can get an estimate of the effects of variables (hazard ratios) without estimating the baseline hazard function. This is a strength of Cox regression, because if you don't estimate the baseline hazard function, then you cannot make an error in it. This is also a weakness of Cox regression, because if you need something else than the hazard ratio, you will typically need the baseline hazard function, which it doesn't estimate. There are ways around that, but these don't fit well with the logic behind the model.

Comment: thanks for the info. I guess I am confused on how to set up the r code to let it know that each new line doesn't represent a new ID. Would it just naturally notice the ID values? Or is there a special way to set this up to allow r to utilize the changing Actuals?

Comment: I don't use R so there is very little I can say about that.